# Getting current date using $date in Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson, retool

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {newDateField : {$toDate : {$multiply : ["$date", 1000]}}}},
    {$match : {newDateField: {$lte: new Date(), $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 86400 * 30)}}}])
```

In the above query, I am trying to get all events that happened in the past 30 days (from now). In the shell, the query runs smoothly. However, I need to convert it to JSON extended. That means that I need to use `$date` keyword instead of `new Date()` as the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.Date) requires.
If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? having the same issue now